# Why do XMP Burster only damage enemy portals?

Tags: ingress

I'm playing Ingress for only a month now, but what I'm wondering is, why do XMP burster (and Ultra Strikes) **only damage enemy portals**?

As far I've learned now XMP bursters are 'neutral', both factions use the very same weapons. So, why does it depend on who fires that weapon?

I think it would be a much more challenging game, if a player had to keep friendly portals in mind while attacking enemy portals. Especially in areas with (extremely) high portal density. (As it is now, it is just a question of resources to take down an enemy portal, regardless of surroundings.)

Comment: maybe you can simply think that friendly-fire is not available for this game.

Comment: Yeah. But Niantic puts so much thought in all the story behind and around the game, so I would be disappointed, if there's no "reason" for that behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what the game is based around (xm) this matter is what allows you to use the tools that you find (i.e xmp bursters). Now when you activate this neutral weapon, you are using some of your own xmp in the way in which your faction uses it. Since the portals on your team are also powered by you teams collective xmp it makes sense that a weapon powered with the same energy would do nothing to your own portals, but negate the power of enemy portals.

I hope that makes sense to you and helps clear up your confusion!

Comment: Is this sourced anywhere or just an explanation?

Comment: @npst this is simply an explanation

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an reasonable explanation. Especially as it also resonates with the "Lore" about the [Jarvis Virus on Wikia](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/JARVIS_Virus). Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer not a problem, I'm glad I was able to answer your question.